# How to capture and add keystrokes to a div element in realtime?

Tags: javascript, html, keystrokes

In the following code i'm trying to get the key presses and add it to my div element. For eg: if i'm pressing random keys such as "fhjbfwjbj" it should be added to the text in div. :

```
<script>
function type()
    {
        var edit = document.getElementById("add");
        edit.innerHTML=edit.innerHTML + //WHAT TO ADD?????;
    }
</script>

<body onkeypress="type()">
<div id="add" style="position:relative; left:600px; top:170px;">

Add to this text

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using a framework like jQuery for this?

Comment: Put `console.log(arguments)` inside of the function and see what the browser sends to your method. Can't you just make the div content editable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
document.body.onkeypress = function(evt) {
  var edit = document.getElementById("add");
  edit.innerHTML=edit.innerHTML + String.fromCharCode(evt.which || evt.keyCode);
}
```

Comment: This will give you strange characters for keys like the ' key and they will all be in caps.

Comment: Really? I'm testing it out in my console right now, and the alphanumeric characters seem to work okay, without converting to caps.

Comment: That is what it has done for me in the past when I have done this; figured it would do it for you. What browser are you using?

Comment: Oh, wow you are right. It was a problem with my code; guess I learned something; thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change onkeypress to onkeyup (that's just a matter of preference, though) and then your function should take in an event arg e.g. `function type(evt)` and the key will be in the keyCode property, i.e. `evt.keyCode`.